# Access Hidden Data on a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

1. I need to access the following website: http://mothoq.com/store/22
2. scroll down till i see the phone icon.
3. click on it, and scrape the phone number.

I have successfully connected to the website, and able to scrape all data needed, except of the phone number.

I have tried to use

```
soup.find_all('p',attrs={"align":"center"})
```

my code is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


records = []
storeId = 22
url = "http://mothoq.com/store/" + str(storeId)
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")
results = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'subtitle'})

for storeData in results:
storeName = soup.find('h1')
url = soup.find('font').text

contacts = soup.find_all('p', attrs={"class":"store_connect_details"})
for storeContact in contacts:
    storePhone    = soup.find_all('p', attrs={"align":"center"})
    storeTwitter  = soup.find('a', attrs={"class":"connect_icon_twitter"})['href']
    storeFacebook = soup.find('a', attrs={"class":"connect_icon_facebook"})['href']
    storeLinkedin = soup.find('a', attrs={"class":"connect_icon_linkedin"})['href']

print(storePhone)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should search for hidden div with id="store-telephone-form" and take second <p> tag from it.

Comment: The code works fine, you can access the phone number by `storePhone[1]`

Comment: @RomanMindlin - If i do this way, it return (out of range). Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @chad storePhone[1] - gives me out of range error.

Comment: @BeginnerScraper if I understood correctly, then the phone number is in `soup.find('div', attrs={"id":"store-telephone-form"}).select('p')[1].text`. It is 920005159

Comment: That's correct Roman. Can you print the len() of storePhone and let us know

Comment: @chad I've changed assignment of `storePhone` , so in my code length of it will be `len('920005159')` exactly. I've attached my code as an answer below.

Comment: @RomanMindlin have you tested you code?

Comment: @t.m.adam I've tested it in a part of my changes. 

`In[16]:soup.find('div', attrs={"id":"store-telephone-form"}).select('p')[1].text

Out[16]:'920005159'`

Comment: @RomanMindlin that part is correct, but this page doesn't have a linkedin link so when you select `'href'` it raises an exception. You could use an if-else or try-except block to catch that. Also you don't need `find_all` for `contacts`, just use `find` as it's one item.

Comment: @t.m.adam You are right. My intention is to answer question asked but not to rewrite all code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search for hidden `div` with `id="store-telephone-form"` and take second 
`<p>` tag from it.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


records = []
storeId = 22
url = "http://mothoq.com/store/" + str(storeId)
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
results = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'subtitle'})

storeName = soup.find('h1')
url = soup.find('font').text

contacts = soup.find_all('p', attrs={"class":"store_connect_details"})

try:
    storePhone = soup.find('div', attrs={"id":"store-telephone-form"}).select('p')[1].text
    storeTwitter  = soup.find('a', attrs={"class":"connect_icon_twitter"}).get('href')
    storeFacebook = soup.find('a', attrs={"class":"connect_icon_facebook"}).get('href')
    storeLinkedin = soup.find('a', attrs={"class":"connect_icon_linkedin"}).get('href')
except:
    pass

print(storePhone)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Yes, For linkedin and other items, I will do some exceptions and error checking. My issue was mainly on the (.select('p'))!